# Change CSS of a div when hovering another (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change the CSS of a div when hovering its parent div.

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="box1" class="hover-on-div-1">
    <img src="images/1.png" alt="" />
    <div id="line1"></div>
    <div class="text_align"><span>Text here</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#box1 {
    height: 295px;
    width: 220px;
    background-color: #86d1f4;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 120px;
    margin-top: 55px;
    color: #0081C5;
}

#box1:hover {
    background-color: #494c5b;
    color: #BFB6AF;
}

#line1 {
    height:1px;
    background:#0081C5;
    width:126px;
    margin-top:67px;
    margin-left:40px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Note: .hover-on-div-1 is the class I use for a JQuery function that changes the image, the `<span>` is used only for a text-transform and the text-align class is pretty self explanatory.

How do I change the .line1 div when hovering over #box1?

I managed to change everything inside the #box1 div when I hover but not the .line1. Did some search on SO but since I'm a total noob when it comes to JQuery/JavaScript it didn't helped too much.

https://jsfiddle.net/nLg8Lr7x/

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle example?

Comment: add code you have tried

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need JS for this - your **#line1 div** is child of **#box1 div**.
Just add some css like this:

```
#box1:hover #line1 {
    /* Changes for #line1 when #box1 hovered */
}
```

Here is [examle on jsbin](http://jsbin.com/yazokigawo/2/edit?html,css,output).

Comment: You sir are a genius! Thank you! Will accept answer in a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it with jQuery you can make use of [`mouseover`](https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) and [`mouseleave`](https://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) functions to change css like below.

**Notes:** I suggest you to make use of [`addClass`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) and [`removeClass`](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) functions instead of setting *hard codded* css in functions.

```
$('#box1').mouseover(function() {
   $('#line1').css("background", "red"); // change css
});
$('#box1').mouseleave(function() {
   $('#line1').css("background", "#0081C5"); // change back css as it was
});
```

```js
$('#box1').mouseover(function() {
  $('#line1').css("background", "red");
});
$('#box1').mouseleave(function() {
  $('#line1').css("background", "#0081C5");
});
```

```css
    #box1 {

      height: 295px;

      width: 220px;

      background-color: #86d1f4;

      float: left;

      margin-left: 30px;

      margin-right: 120px;

      margin-top: 55px;

      color: #0081C5;

    }

    #box1:hover {

      background-color: #494c5b;

      color: #BFB6AF;

    }

    #line1 {

      height: 1px;

      background: #0081C5;

      width: 126px;

      margin-top: 67px;

      margin-left: 40px;

      position: absolute;

    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box1" class="hover-on-div-1">
  <img src="images/1.png" alt="" />
  <div id="line1"></div>
  <div class="text_align"><span>Text here</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution, it's nice to see the solution to my question done through JQuery.